# How do I clip the edges of my tab bar container in flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, user-experience, tabbar

I have a container at the bottom of my screen that has a BottomNavigationBar. I want the container to get the colour of my background. Even after adding CLipRRect it wasn't getting corrected. I also tried to make the container transparent but it showed me an error where I couldn't assign a colour to my container and give it a boxDecoration.I want the excess white part to merge into my background.

//edited

**How do I get rid of the shadow from the background?**
[image]

```
Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) => ClipRect(
    child: Container(
        height: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(52.0)),
          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                offset: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                blurRadius: 52.0),
          ],
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(52.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(52.0)),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFFE524B),
            unselectedItemColor: Color(0xFFFF8C3B),
            onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
            currentIndex: selectedIndex,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Entypo.home,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  title: Text('')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Entypo.game_controller,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  title: Text('[![enter image description here][1]][1]')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Entypo.wallet,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  title: Text('')),
            ],
          ),
        )),
  );
```

Comment: You can put the color property inside the BoxDecoration. It will fix the error you received, but I'm not sure it will achieve what you want. Can you try it?

Comment: No I tried that but its not merging into my background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually not a problem with the bottom navigation bar. You need to set "extendBody" to "true" for the parent Scaffold widget. This will extend the scaffold body content all the way down to the bottom of the screen!

```
Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(selectedIndex),
);
```

Comment: Just had another question how do I resolve the shadow appearing in this? **question edited**

Comment: If you have a separate question, I suggest you open a new one. This one has been solved.

Comment: @SimranAswani You're welcome! Sorry, but I'm not sure which shadow exactly you are referring to. Maybe it's best if you could open another question with a new screenshot of the shadow you want to remove. I will be sticking around to answer that one too!